# Express Checkout Button Not Showing

Tags: cart, template, paypal-express

I've set up PayPal Express Checkout, however, I'm in a position now where I need to test it.
The button does not appear on the cart page.

Printing the following method reveals that PayPal is enabled:

```
$this->getMethods('methods');
```

However, the following is empty for the PayPal Express Checkout:

```
$this->getMethodHtml($method);
```

Without the button, and the associated data attached to it, I cannot navigation to `/paypal/express/start` because I get a security error.

Shortcut on Shopping Cart is marked as Yes, so I'm struggling to understand why it's not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by manually including the button. This isn't ideal, obviously, and I had to connect it manually to the PayPal API, but it works, nonetheless.